# How do I add Serilog to a service collection for my unit test

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest, serilog

In our .Net Core 3.1 project we log using Serilog

In the set-up of my test I create a ServiceCollection so I can new up my classes I use in the tests using a service collection \ - provider.
I have a repository that uses both a DbContext and a Serilog logger.

```
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyApp.Persistency
{
    public class MyRepository : IMyRepository

{
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public OpvragenOnbekendeBurgerRegistratieRepository(DataContext dataContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }
...
}
```

In my test class:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
         var diCollection =
         new ServiceCollection()
             .AddSingleton(new SqlConnectionOption(_connectionstring))
             .AddDbContext<DataContext>(
                options =>
                {
                   options.UseSqlServer(_connectionstring);
                }
              )
              ...               
              xxx Add some kind of Serilog registration xxx
              ...
              .AddTransient<IMyRepositoy,MyRepository>();
           _di = diCollection.BuildServiceProvider;
      }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyRepositoryTest()
    {  
        // arrange
        var myRepository = _di.GetRequiredService<IMyRepository>();
        ...
    }
```

I have seen a zillion different code samples, but none seem to work only a container, instead of a full
blown host. A dummy that logs nothing would be acceptable, but logging to the testconsole would of course be epic.

Comment: Why don't you... just add it... in the same way you normally would?

Comment: @Ian Kemp They provide a "UseSerilog" extension method, but that requires a hostbuilder as well. Which I don't have

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add Serilog to a `ServiceCollection` instance:

```cs
new ServiceCollection()
    //...
    .AddLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog(dispose: true))
    //...
```

Serilog configuration:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    //...
    .CreateLogger();
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics)

Comment: I followed the above, but still cannot get this to work. I still get an exception that Serilog.ILogger cannot be resolved.